# Hardware volume button not working on locked phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing a simple app in which i am the counting of volume button press 3 times. If counter is equal to three then some action will happen.

My problem is when i press the hardware volume button when phone is locked then `onReceive()` method of `BroadcastReceiver` is not called. Its working fine when phone is unlocked.

Is there any way or trick that When i press volume up button in locked mode then my counter increase and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched on this and conclusion is that Its is not possible.

But I did in some way but its not good approach because It will drain the battery too much.

I start the media player in background with zero volume. Now volume keys start working when even mobile is locked. As example Music app in which volume buttons work even when mobile is locked.

Comment: Any chance you could explain how you did this? I tried starting a background service which creates and starts a mediaplayer on 0 volume, but the volume keys still don't work when the phone screen is off.

Comment: @domji84 How you are doing.?